# What CPUs does the Spoiler attack affect?

Tags: side-channel, intel, speculative-execution

I see on different websites different information about the Spoiler Attack. Some websites say all Intel CPUs are vulnerable and other websites say only Intel Core CPUs are vulnerable.

Are Intel Xeon CPUs vulnerable?

Answer (score 1):

Their whitepaper says "The leakage can be exploited by a
limited set of instructions, which is visible in all Intel generations starting from the 1
st generation of Intel Core processors,
independent of the OS and also works from within virtual machines and sandboxed environments"

In a table of results they show a Xeon CPU being vulnerable specifically Intel Xeon E5-2670v2 and Intel Xeon E5-2640v3

Answer (score 1):

From page 7 of the [research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.00446.pdf):

> While the leakage exists on ***all Intel Core processors*** starting from the
>   first generation, the timing effect is higher for the more recent
>   generations with a bigger store buffer size. ***The analyzed ARM and AMD
>   processors do not show similar behaviour***.

Intel "Core" processors must refer to all modern Intel high-performance processors since the [Core microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_(microarchitecture)) was released in 2006. You can tell this because the table on that same page shows more recent Ivy Bridge Xeons and Kaby Lake i7s as also vulnerable.